# Reduce a large struct into a small one?

Tags: go

Say I make a call to an api, which returns a slice of structs, each with a load of methods and fields, but I only want to use one field per each element of the returned values. How can I do this?

For instance, I call out to an API, and it returns a slice of x elements, each which has  4 values and 13method, but I only want 1 value and 0 methods (the slice of fetus structs). How can I marshall this into my own struct? eg:

```
func GETApi() []fetus {
//doGet() returns a slice of persons, which are described below 
a := doGet()  // this gets many detailed persons as a slice, but I just want them as a slice of fetus
/*
 type person struct {
  id: 
  age:
  height: 
  width:
 }

func (a *person) GetHeight() int { ... }
func (a *person) GetWidth() int { ... }
func (a *person) GetLaught() int { ... }

// I want to return a slice of these ([]fetus)
type fetus struct {
  id: 
 }
var f fetus 
f := a  // how can I condense said slice of persons into a slice of fetus
return f
*/
```

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you could create a slice for Fetus, loop over the range of the slice of Persons, creating a Fetus each iteration and adding them to the slice of fetus'.

Comment: Note that Methods do no contribute to the size of a value.

Comment: "I only want to use one field per each element of the returned values" - so only use what you need. Without more information about the use case, the obvious solution is "do nothing". Is this code causing excessive memory use? Are you marshaling these to JSON and need to exclude fields? Is there some particular reason you actually need to get rid of the fields you don't explicitly need here?

Comment: So its not about size, but how to mock these structs in unit tests. If I'm writing a unit test for a function that uses Person as a result, I have to mock out all of Person even though I am using just a few fields, as the unit test expects something of type Person.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something like this?

```
package main

type Person struct {
    Id string
    Name string
    Age string
    LotsOfOtherFields string
}

type Fetus struct {
    Id string
}

func main() {
    persons := []Person{
        {Id: "a", Name: "John"},
        {Id: "b", Name: "Steve"},
        {Id: "c", Name: "Fred"},
    }

    fetuses := make([]Fetus, len(persons))
    for i, p := range persons {
        // Create a new fetus struct and pluck the ID from the person struct
        fetuses[i] = Fetus{Id: p.Id}
    }
}
```